# Is there an explanation to why my stuffy nose seemingly disappears when I cover my nose while breathing?

Tags: research, common-cold, nose, sneeze-sneezing

Ever since I was a kid, I noticed that whenever my nose was stuffy, breathing through my handkerchief seemed to instantly make me breathe normal again.
It has happened each time without fail for years, so I know that it is not a random occurence that might throw me off.

1) The kerchief needs to stay really close to my nose, touching it. I tried covering it only half, and it still does work to a limiting covering area.

2) It usually requires a few folds to make that work. If I try it without any folds, it works only if I flare my nostrils. (Too many folds would lead to less air passing through)

3) Most importantly: the most optimal way, as I have found, is to keep an opening on the top (near the eyes) that let the air enter. If I tighten the kerchief, it doesn't work at all (that's why masks don't work for me).

*It also works with merely covering my nose with my hand and letting the air enter from the top*

*My best hypothesis: I think the covering acts as a wind breaker. Which somehow helps. But merely breathing slowly (which might have a similar effect) absolutely doesn't work.*

(This works for stuffy nose due to cold, but I don't know if it works for an allergy.
I don't leave it covered while sleeping because when I tried it as a kid, I always bled through my nose; but that just might be because of a complication that makes me bleed through my nose more often than other people)

Also, can someone comment if they have noticed something similar? I don't know if this is a particular case.